# Proto file or similar available for google assistant conversation webhook?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

Google assistant has a json webhook api called the 'conversation webhook' [(api documentation)](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/Shared.Types/AppRequest) and a node.js client library for it [here](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs).

Question: is there a .proto protobuffers file or some other single-source-of-truth file that I can use to help me get started writing a server for this webhook in a language other than node.js?

More info:

- in my case I'd like to handle the webhook in go (golang), but I expect others would want to create a webhook server for google assistant actions in python, java, etc.
- basically I'm looking for whatever google uses as the single source of truth for this api. I assume the online documentation (see first link above) is auto-generated from a file and not written by hand.
- I'm really hoping there's a .proto file that is or can be made available so that go/python/java/etc. client libraries can be (somewhat) auto-generated. Lots of google's public api's have this available, see *github.com/googleapis*. The new assistant sdk for embedding the assistant in a device also has a proto file for it's interface definition, see *assistant/embedded* at *github.com/google-apis*.

Thanks in advance for any help.

PS: if a proto file isn't available and there are googlers reading this, please can you try to make one available! I could list the many benefits of having one available to the community, but then I'd be stupidly trying to sell protobuffers to googlers! So I'll leave it there. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find anything provided by google which authoritatively showed the **`request/response`** flow for conversation actions. I used a couple implementations I found on GitHub to get my python app working. I found [Github - actions-on-google-php](https://github.com/zhuowei/actions-on-google-php)  and [Github  -  google-action-three-doors](https://github.com/eisenzopf/google-action-three-doors/tree/master/json)   helpful in showing the JSON passed back and forth in the protocol.